# send InApp Only FCM messages to webapp

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

How can I send message to my webapp user that will not show when the App is in the background; i tried to use the following:

```
{
   "notification": {
     "title": "A",
     "body": "A",
     "icon": "firebase-logo.png",
     "click_action": "htts://firebase.com"
   },
    "data" : {
     "inAppOnly": "true"
    },
   "to": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
 }
```

and then in the `fcm-messaging-sw.js` check for `payload.data.inAppOnly` flag

```
  if (payload.data.inAppOnly === true) { 
    return null
  } else {
    return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle,
    notificationOptions) 
  }
```

However the message always shows when app is in background.

Comment: Are you using React Native? If so which library?

Comment: @AlexanderVitanov it is webapp i'm using JS SDK